# Getting index of subarray in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and wonder what is the best way to get the index of subarray, consider the following array of vectors

```
vec = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

I would like to get the index of the element `[4, 5, 6]`, however I can not use `getindex()`, execution of the following code:

```
getindex(vec, [1, 2, 3])
```

gives:

```
BoundsError: attempt to access 2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1} at index [[1, 2, 3]]
```

So I wonder if there are any effective build-in methods for doing this. Of course I can map this array of vectors into another array of numbers and do a search inside new array of numbers, but it isn't really a solution what I expect.

Second question is how do I learn more about search methods in Julia and their performances. I guess the theoretical speed of search scales like `\sqrt(N)` however depending on the certain method the real code time may vary significantly.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the name of the function you might be mislead: `getindex` retrieves the *value* stored at an *index*.

If you want to find the *index* of something in an array you can make use of find* methods `findfirst`, `findall`...

```
julia> vec=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3]
 [4, 5, 6]

julia> i = findfirst(x->x==[4,5,6],vec)
2

julia> vec[i]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 5
 6
```

Concerning your second question:

It's best to inform yourself about search/sort algorithms in general (e.g. https://codeburst.io/algorithms-i-searching-and-sorting-algorithms-56497dbaef20?gi=3bdbf8cbaca0), because the performance depends much more on the chosen algorithm than on the language specific implementation. E.g. time complexity can be very different (O(n), O(log(n),...).

Comment: Our identical answers cross-posted :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you've misunderstood what `getindex` does. It's the function that gets called by `[]`, so

```
julia> getindex(vec, 2)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 5
 6
```

All search (or "find") methods in Julia take a function as it's first argument, and find where the function evaluates to `true`. To find a particular element, use `isequal` or `==` (they are equivalent):

```
julia> findall(==([1,2,3]), vec)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
```